# c++ stateful functor that populates vectors

Tags: c++, boost, functor, boost-geometry

I have a question regarding functors. I built a simple class:

```
    class PolygonPrinter { 
        private:
            std::vector<float> x;
            std::vector<float> y;
        public:
            inline void operator()(Point& p) {
                x.push_back(boost::geometry::get<0>(p));
                y.push_back(boost::geometry::get<1>(p));
            }

            void printPoints() {
                for(int i=0; i < x.size(); i++) {
                    std::cout << "(" 
                              << x[i] << "," << y[i] 
                              << ")" << std::endl;
                }
            }
    }
```

Which I wanted to use as a functor. This is used in something like

```
    PolygonPrinter<point_2d> polyPrinter;
    boost::geometry::for_each_point( polygon, polyPrinter );
    polyPrinter.printPoints();
```

Now it seems the functor part works fine as I see the vectors being populated with all the polygon elements (so the for_each_point works as expected), however, the third call ( printPoints ) prints no points and in fact both vectors are empty. I guess this behaviour is expected, however, I cannot understand how the vectors are cleared. I thought you could have stateful functors.

Why are the vector fields x and y in the polyPrinter instance empty?

Comment: My guess, your for_each_point is getting a copy of original polyPrinter. Thus, copy is populated with points, you see it, but original is still empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std` algorithms copy your functor.  `boost` probably does the same.

You can `std::ref( functor )` to pass it via pseudo-ref, and you'll get the behaviour you want.

```
boost::geometry::for_each_point( polygon, std::ref(polyPrinter) );
```

As an aside, your use of `inline` is redundant: all methods defined in the body of a class are implicitly `inline`.  This is the source of some fun to track down bugs.

Comment: @alvini if this solves your problem, the official way to mark it as the answer is to give it a checkmark.  There is a button to its left to press.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the same instance of `PolygonPrinter`.

The definition from the [Boost API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/for_each/for_each_point.html) is:

```
template<typename Geometry, typename Functor>
Functor for_each_point(Geometry & geometry, Functor f)
```

The functor is passed by copy! So you actually create a new instance for Boost API to work with and therefore it isn't affecting your instance. If you would like to capture the new state (after using the `for_each_point`) use the return value to reassign your instance with the one Boost returns. Of course, *this assumes your copy constructor does what you expect*: copies the values you need over in some way. In your specific case, you have the default copy constructor so it should work as expected.

```
PolygonPrinter<point_2d> polyPrinter;
polyPrinter = boost::geometry::for_each_point( polygon, polyPrinter );
polyPrinter.printPoints();
```

Comment: I got it! Thanks. I should've thought of this.